# here i am creating table row by giving dynamically data for table data . But i didn't get the data by their id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

here i am creating table row by giving dynamically data for table data . But i didn't get the data by their id

```js
if(xmlhttp.status == 200)
                        {
                          var adminList = xmlhttp.responseJSON;
                          var outputStr = '';
                          for(var i = 0; i < adminList.length; i++)
                          {
                            outputStr += '<tr><td id="tdusername">' + adminList[i].username + '</td><td id="tdfullname">' + adminList[i].fullName + '</td><td id="tdemail">'+ adminList[i].email+'</td><td id="tdedit">'+adminList[i].id+'</td></tr>';
                          }
                          $('#admin_list tbody').html(outputStr);
            else
                    {
                      $('#msg').html(xmlhttp.status + ": " + xmlhttp.statusText);
                    }
```

Comment: what is the issue ?

Comment: here after generating the table how can i get the specific table data by their id ? i gave id of every td dynamically but it didn't work @GeorgeBailey

Comment: you are assigning the same ID to all of them. Ids must be unique. You can use `id="tdusername"+i` etc. If this function executes only once

Comment: no its not working. I am using this $('#tdedit').click(adminInfo); to call the function by clicking that data in the table but its not working. @GeorgeBailey

Comment: $('#tdedit').val().toString() this i used to get the data

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are clicking on data to get specific row data, then i suggest to add an id to `<tr>`

```
 var outputStr ='<table>';
 for(var i = 0; i < adminList.length; i++)
 {
  outputStr += '<tr id="tdedit'+adminList[i].id+'" onclick="showdata('+adminList[i].id+')"><td id="tdusername">' + adminList[i].username + '</td><td id="tdfullname">' + adminList[i].fullName + '</td><td id="tdemail">'+ adminList[i].email+'</td><td id="tdedit">'+adminList[i].id+'</td></tr>';
 }
outputStr +='</table>';

function showdata(id){
  var row = document.getElementById('tdedit'+id);
  //now you can access all column by their index
  var username=row.cells[0].innerHTML;
  var fullname=row.cells[1].innerHTML;
  var email=row.cells[2].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: No Still its not working. Showing "Uncaught ReferenceError: showdata is not defined at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick" @crack_iT

Comment: You have to add showdata function I provided, outside any other JavaScript function

Comment: can you please tell me how to use or get the value of cells[0],cells[1]. It showing this in the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at showdata (script.js:93) at HTMLTableRowElement.onclick ((index):1)" @crack_iT

Comment: Can you console.log(Id, row); after comment in showdata() and let me know result

Comment: after  giving console.log(id,row) it shows this with corresponding row click 
1 w.fn.init [tr#tdedit1]
5 w.fn.init [tr#tdedit5]
4 w.fn.init [tr#tdedit4]

Comment: Looks like you are not adding <table> tag